Updating the IconLabel after embedding an object using AddOLEObject
I have a series of embedded objects (Excel sheets, Acrobat docs, etc...) in a PowerPoint presentation.
They each have IconLabels.
For some reason the Acrobat objects are not accepting my customized text for IconLabels, displaying , while the embedded Excel objects do. So I'd like to find a way to set the IconLabel after embedding it but I can't find a way to do so.
Here is how I embed the object:
Set TempObject = ActivePresentation.Slides(k).Shapes.AddOLEObject(Left:=leftCord, Top:=topCord, _
Width:=sWidth, Height:=sHeight, _
DisplayAsIcon:=True, FileName:=sPath, IconLabel:=iconValue)
Is there any way to update the IconLabel after being embedded?
Thanks.
